# Java convert Unicode to original language

Tags: unicode

I have array such this

```
String[] array ={"062C06450644","062C06280644"}
```

I want to translate this unicode to the original language using this code:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(String arr:array)
{
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i+=4)
    {
        String s = arr.substring(i,i+4);
        stringBuilder.append((char) Integer.parseInt(s,16));
    }

    System.out.println("sb:"+stringBuilder);
}
```

The result:

```
sb: جمل
sb: جملجبل
```

**The problem:**
this code append the 2nd word to 1st and so on.

**The question:**
How i translate each word without append each word to the word before.

I want the result to be such

```
sb:جمل
sb:جبل
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a clean `StringBuilder` for each word. Just swap the first two rows:

```
for(String arr:array) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i+=4) {
        String s = arr.substring(i,i+4);
        stringBuilder.append((char) Integer.parseInt(s,16));
    }

    System.out.println("sb:"+stringBuilder);
}
```

Alternatively, you can clear the `StringBuilder`at the end of the outer loop with `stringBuilder.setLength(0)`.

Comment: @Usagi Miyamoto: Yes, you're right. I've updated my post.